# Where can I learn more about how to use the GRUB `ntldr` command (module?)

Tags: windows, grub2

I recently stumbled across the GRUB `ntldr` module.

Apparently one of the things it can be used for is as an alternative to `chainloader` to boot the NT >= 6.0 versions of Windows as in the example below. (Very handy if the Volume Boot Record for a Windows partition is, uh, corrupted.)

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (bootmgr on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    insmod ntldr
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1EA0019AA0017A13
    ntldr ($root)/bootmgr
}
```

Where can I learn more about how this boot directive can be used? I did not see it listed when I looked in the [**HTML version**](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html) of the [*GNU GRUB manual*](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/).

---

#### Replying to ckhan's answer

Thank you very much! I had pretty much decided I would have to try digging through the source code to learn more about the GRUB `ntldr` command/module. But you have done a much better job than I would have.

It never would have occurred to me to look at the email archives to see what design discussions the person who wrote the code might have had. That method sounds like it could be very helpful in the future. Thanks for mentioning it.

**My thoughts about GRUB `ntldr` support**

1. While I'm not really sure how much the distinction means, `ntldr` is a module, not a command. Or perhaps a dynamically loaded command if you wish.

   Following your [source code link](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/loader/i386/pc/ntldr.c) and looking at lines 152 (`GRUB_MOD_INIT`) and 159 (`GRUB_MOD_FINI`) you can see the code to load and ... I'm guessing ... unload the module.

   GRUB apparently implements many functions which you might think are "*commands*" as modules. The only difference in usage that I'm aware of is that before using a module one must ensure it has been loaded with the command `insmod ntldr`.

   *Aside:* I always wondered why GRUB does not support `reboot`. It turns out the command exists, but it is a module. If `reboot` returns `unknown command`, then `insmod reboot` allows GRUB to "remember" the `reboot` command.

   *Aside:* When and why GRUB might "*unload*" a module, I have no idea yet. Maybe it is the result of something similar to "*garbage collection*"?? I have noticed that once loaded the modules seem to persist, even after a system is powered down and rebooted. Of course, you cannot **depend** on that, but that appears to be how it often works in practice.
2. It is interesting that they based `ntldr` on `chainloader`. I have not looked at the `chainloader.c` code. I guess it probably also does a relocating load in Intel 16-bit *real* mode?

   I **am** rather glad they did not implement `ntldr` as an option of `chainloader`. I agree with Vladimir. Whatever the similarities under the covers, the usage syntax is very different. The current approach is less kludgy.
3. It is also interesting to see the apparent lack of enthusiasm for adding this command to GRUB. Apparently the GRUB developers thought damage to the Windows *Partition Boot Record (PBR)* was extremely unlikely. However, I can sketch out how to do it during an ordinary enough install.

   Start by assuming a user has Windows installed on their system. They now install Ubuntu (12.04 LTS) "*alongside*" Windows. At one point during the Ubuntu install they can apparently decide where they want GRUB to be installed. For reasons I cannot begin to guess at, some of them decide to install GRUB into the partition Windows is installed in.

   The install completes and they can successfully start Ubuntu. However, when they try to start Windows by selecting the entry in the GRUB menu, Windows does **not** start. Instead attempting to start Windows with GRUB just re-displays the GRUB menu?

   Why? Well, apparently when they elected to install GRUB into the windows partition part of what actually happened was the PBR for the Windows partition was over-written with GRUB's PBR. So `chainloader +1` does not chain load a Windows bootloader, but instead re-loads GRUB.

   IMO, the safest *quick* way to allow a user to boot Windows in that situation is to use the GRUB's new `ntldr`. I wonder if this would be of interest to the developers. I expect they did not anticipate this scenario.

I wonder what bootloaders other than the Windows ones, `ntldr` and `bootmgr`, the GRUB `ntldr` command might be able to load?

Comment: Great stuff! I really think you should drop a line on the grub-devel mailing list, and ask them to take a peek at this question and maybe chime in on some of the unanswered questions and/or correct some of our assumptions. Thanks for opening the question in the first place!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Researching the undocumented feature

You're right the `ntldr` command (it is command, not module) is not documented. So it's a great excuse
for some adventures in
[code archaeology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_archaeology).

Whenever I find an undocumented feature, first thing to do is check sources.

- The source at the [Savannah git repo](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/log/grub-core/loader/i386/pc/ntldr.c)
  shows that it was merged into the main line in August 2010.
- The source branch seems no more, but you can still see it [came into existence
  earlier that year](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/commit/?id=b883356cf6cfb07ee36eaf14ea590e2318efc4ae), in April 2010. The checkin comment, from "Vladimir 'phcoder' Serbinenko" was

  ```
  ntldr support. (based on information from nyu but no code from him)
  ```

It's based very closely on the `chainloader` command, so much so that
the file name in the header comment still hasn't been updated.

Now that we have an exact checkin, and a name, we can check mailing
archives.  You can see where the developers had the discussing about
adding this feature a year earlier on the
[grub-devel mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2009-08/msg00040.html):

Some relevant excerpts from that thread:

> **Robert Millan** This patch implements a loader for NTLDR boot semantics (which are
>   the same in BootMGR, hence both are supported)
>
> **Robert Millan** If we want this feature at all, I think it should be an option in the
>   chainloader rather than a standalone command.  It's almost the same as
>   the chainloader really, the only difference is that ntldr is load after
>   PBR by GRUB instead of by PBR itself.
>
> **Vladimir Serbinenko** I don't think it's of any problem since
>   ntldr uses this PBR only as superblock to identify the partition. As
>   such I would rather consider this loading as a special case of passing
>   $root, just the form of it is a bit weird
>
> **Yves Blusseau** About the command, i think that it will be simpler for the user if we have
>   only one command: chainloader (like in grub4dos) that will try to detect the
>   type of the bootloader. This is only my personal opinion.
>
> **Vladimir Serbinenko** I don't agree with this. chainloader and ntldr don't share the same
>   syntax: chainloader expects a bootsector whereas ntldr expects an
>   ntldr ot bootmgr file. GRUB2 is done to break with bad design
>   decisions of GRUB1 one of them being "kernel" command. GRUB4DOS
>   follows GRUB1 on this subject.
>
> **Robert Millan** Alright.  Let's make it a separate command.  I think it should still share
>   code with chainloader.c though (with some ifdefs).

## Answering your question

After poring over all that, what do we know about how it can be used?

- It's based on chainloader.
- It takes a single argument: the file to open.
- It avoids the partition boot record: so it can bypass corruption there.
  See [this post](https://grub-devel.gnu.narkive.com/dp6vcCZf/patch-ntldr-support#post5) detailing how they tested that.
- It's [only about 160 lines of code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/loader/i386/pc/ntldr.c), you can see there's not much else there.

Hope this was useful!